# How is the level of a Greater Rift Keystone decided?

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to know 2 things :

- What determines the level of a Greater Rift Keystone level during the first trial ?
- What determines how many levels Urushi gives to the next Greater Rift Keystone at the end of a Greater Rift ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The level of the Greater Rift Keystone obtained by completing the Realm of Trials is determined by the wave you killed last. The wave level is determined by how fast you killed the previous wave (note the timer on each wave). It always starts at 1.

This metric has been slightly described in [more detail](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14579008081#1) for multiplayer groups. A group of 2 receives a key equal to the level complete minus 4, group of 3 gets a key equal to minus 5, and a group of 4 gets -6.

What determines how many levels Urushi gives to the next Greater Rift Keystone at the end of a Greater Rift ?

Of 15 minutes,
0-3 minutes taken: level + 9
3-4 : +8
4-5 : +7
5-6 : +6
6-7 : +5
7-8 : +4
8-9 : +3
9-10 : +2
10:30+ : +1

Comment: And what is the relation between the # of the wave during the trial and the number of the key. For example at wave level 46 I recieve a key level 40, wave 41 is a key level 35 : how does that work ?

Comment: @WizLiz - The keystone trial has been since slightly tweaked I believe, although I could not find any posts actually saying anything about it. From observation, it seems to be that you get the key level of the last wave you defeated without the timer going below 30%.

Comment: I think you can update your answer : http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14579008081

Comment: @WizLiz - I included the group modification numbers to the Greater Rift Keystone.

Comment: I finished a rift in 7:05 and got +4.  I dont know how exactly your list categorizes that.   does "4: +8" mean < 4 minutes?  If so, then there is no time for 10-11 minutes remaining.

Comment: From my own testing, anything over 10:30 is +1.  10:26 is +2

Comment: This answer is out of date. It's 10:30 for +1